# Move ViewModel definition into package-level method

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to move:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FooViewModel::class.java)
```

into a package-level method. Something like this:

```
fun <T1, T2> T1.getViewModel(target: T1, targetViewModelClass: T2): Lazy<T2> {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(target).get(targetViewModelClass::class.java)
}
```

However this gives me 2 errors:

[image]

and

[image]

---

**Question:** is there any way to complete this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `T1` parameter must be of type `Fragment` or `FragmentActivity`. Currently it is none.
Also, to call `::class.java`, the type must be non-nullable. Currently it is `T2: Any?`. Furthermore, `T2` must extend `ViewModel`.
Finally, for an easy API you may use a [reified type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

You might want to write:

```
inline fun <reified T: ViewModel> Fragment.getViewModel(): Lazy<T> {
  return lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(T::class.java) }
}
```

You can now use this as:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment {

  fun foo() {
    val viewModelLazy = getViewModel<MyViewModel>()
  }
}
```

You can do the same for `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: `T` needs to extend `ViewModel`.

Comment: I like this solution. One thing to change `return ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(T::class.java)` should be put inside `lazy { ... }`.

Comment: @Oleg Great! Perhaps you could edit the answer with what you mean exactly.

Comment: I mean, that if a method returns `Lazy<T>` the return statement has to be `return lazy { foo }`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
fun <T1: Fragment, T2: Any> T1.getViewModel(targetViewModelClass: KClass<T2>): Lazy<T2> {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(targetViewModelClass.java)
}
```

Usage:

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    fun foo() {
        getViewModel(SomeViewModel::class)
    }

}
```

The first problem was that `T1` could be any type in your function, but the `of` method only takes a `Fragment` or a `FragmentActivity`. Using `T1: Fragment` confines `T1` to be a `Fragment` (you could also make this `FragmentActivity`, of course).

The second problem seems to be that `targetViewModelClass` might be null, you can take care of this by restricting `T2` to be a subtype of `Any`, which is the base class of all non-nullable types in Kotlin. This will guarantee that `null` can't be passed in as that parameter.

Finally, as per @Kirill Rakhman's advice, I've adjusted the second parameter so that the function can be called with a `KClass` instance.

Here are the official docs about [generic constraints](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints) and [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

Comment: I think what OP is trying to do is pass a `Class<T2>` instance as second parameter. Think about, what sense does it make to pass an instance of the `ViewModel` if you want to retrieve a `ViewModel`?

Comment: Fixed up my answer, I tried to keep it in the spirit of the original code. @nhaarman has the more idiomatic solution in the other answer though :)